# Formatting InnerHtml Text with RegEx not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, regex

Technology: Asp.Net 4.5 WebForms

I am using the following javascript function to color text in a code block. It actually works if I halt the code with an alert immediately after the function. But the regex rendering doesn't stick. How can I get the results to render after function is completed? Below is a small sample.

CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
    .blue
    {
        color: blue;
    }

    .demo
    {
        background-color: gainsboro; 
        width: 300px; 
        height: 100px; 
        padding: 5px;
    }
</style>
```

JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Prettyfy() {
        var keys = ["Dim", "As", "String"]

        for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
            var value = keys[i];
            var str = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;
            var regexExpression = "(?!(?:[^<]+>|[^>]+<\\/a>))\\b(" + value + ")\\b";
            var regex = new RegExp(regexExpression, "ig");
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = str.replace(regex, '<span class="blue">' + value + '</span>');
        }

        alert(document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML);
    }
</script>
```

HTML

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server"> <pre id="demo" class="demo">
            <code>
    dim motor as string
    dim reducer as string
            </code>
        </pre>

        <br />
        <button onclick="Prettyfy()">Prettyfy Code</button>
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is very likely to be that your form is causing the page to be repainted by default. Add a "type" attribute to your `<button>`:

```
<button type=button onclick="Prettyfy()">
```

(It's not clear why there's a form at all.)

Comment: Yes, that worked out just fine. Thanks. There is a form because I will be using this in Asp.Net Web Application. Forgot to mention in post. I'll update that.